# backbone.js todomvc add more attributes to model

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, collections, model

I want to try out Backbone.js and started with the famous TodoMVC-App. I want to add some more attributes via input fields (orgiginally there is only one input field with "todo"), but I cant figure out how.

Before I was trying Angular.js and that was a little bit easier - now I am stucked at the point how I should add more attributes per input fields.

Can anyone give me a hint whats the best/easiest way to achieve this?

Some relevant code snippets:

Index.html:

```
    <tr class="userInputs" >
        <td><input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus style="width: 150px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="newQuantity"/></td>

        <td colspan="2"><a ><img src="img/plus.png" id="addItem"></a></td>

    </tr>
```

model/todo.js

```
app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // Default attributes for the todo
    // and ensure that each todo created has `title` and `completed` keys.
    defaults: {
        title: '',
        quantity: 0,
        completed: false
    }

});
```

views/app.js:

```
initialize: function() {
            this.allCheckbox = this.$('#toggle-all')[0];
            this.$input = this.$('#new-todo');
            this.$footer = this.$('#footer');
            this.$main = this.$('#main');

            this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'add', this.addOne);
            this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'reset', this.addAll);
            this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'change:completed', this.filterOne);
            this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'filter', this.filterAll);
            this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'all', this.render);

            app.Todos.fetch();
        }

addOne: function( todo ) {
    var view = new app.TodoView({ model: todo });
    $('#todo-list').append( view.render().el );
}

newAttributes: function() {
    return {
        title: this.$input.val().trim(),
        quantity: this.$input.val().trim(),
        order: app.Todos.nextOrder(),
        completed: false
    };
}

createOnEnter: function(e) {

    app.Todos.create( this.newAttributes() );
    this.$input.val('');
}
```

Hope this is enough information, otherwise please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the way it's done for the title.
Add a new input.
Change the `appView#newAttributes` method to pass the new input's value to the model.
Change the `appView#createOnEnter` method to reset the field.
Change the `#item-template` to include the new attribute in your Todo template.

Everything else will be automatic (including setting the new attribute to the model (passed as argument) and passing the new attribute to the template (because we use the `Model#toJSON` method)).

**Edit:**
`this.$input` is a reference to `this.$('#new-todo')` (see the `initialize` method) so its val is the title. You need to create a new var:
In `initialize`:

```
this.$quantity = this.$('#newQuantity');
```

In `newAttributes`:

```
quantity: this.$quantity.val();
// you're not making any check here
// add one if necessary (you can use underscore), eg
// _.isNumber(quantity = this.$('#newQuantity')) ? quantity : 0
// number being declared before, else it'd be global
```

In `createOnEnter`:

```
this.$quantity.val('');
```

Comment: First, thanks for your help, could you be so kind and explain it to me a little bit more precisely? I am really an absolute beginner to backbone.js :-)

Comment: I edited my answer, now I have included the appView#newAttributes and appView#createOnEnter which I have already changed for the new input field, is this correct like that?

Comment: Oh god, I thank you so much Loamhoof! Really, big thanks to you guy! Now I understand and I have learned a lot...I was really confused with the identifier "input" :-)